# Sorting based on two field dependency in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am retrieving the data from the MongoDB database. In the data object, there are three fields `_id`, `order`, `parent`. these seem like

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "parent" : 0,
  "order" : 1,
}
{
  "_id" : 2, 
  "parent" : 0,
  "order" : 2,
}
{
  "_id" : 3,
  "parent" : 5,
  "order" : 1,
}
{
  "_id" : 4,
  "parent" : 5,
  "order" : 2,
}
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "parent" : 0,
  "order" : 3,
}
{
  "_id" : 6,
  "parent" : 2,
  "order" : 1,
}
{
  "_id" : 7,
  "parent" : 2,
  "order" : 2,
}
```

By using the sort query in the MongoDB shell it will also produce the same result

```
 db.menu.find().sort({_id:1,parent:1,order:1}).pretty()
```

Expected result is this:-

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "parent" : 0,
  "order" : 1,
}
{
  "_id" : 2, 
  "parent" : 0,
  "order" : 2,
}
{
  "_id" : 6,
  "parent" : 2,
  "order" : 1,
}
{
  "_id" : 7,
  "parent" : 2,
  "order" : 2,
}
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "parent" : 0,
  "order" : 3,
}
{
  "_id" : 3,
  "parent" : 5,
  "order" : 1,
}
{
  "_id" : 4,
  "parent" : 5,
  "order" : 2,
}
```

By using which query Should I got my expected result?

Comment: What is the order of your sorting? It seems random output.

Comment: @HardikShah firstly it will sort the ids and then it will combine the record by matching parent value to the id value with respect to order field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very tough to sort by dependency in a normal scenario.
Hence, we will accumulate priority first and then sort it with the help of aggregation.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {$project: {
    "id":"$id",
    "parent":1,
    "order":1,
    "accumulator":{$cond:[{$gt:["$parent","$order"]}, "$parent", "$order"]}
  }},
  {$sort: {"accumulator": 1}},
  {$project:{
    "id":"$id",
    "parent":1,
    "order":1
  }}
])
```

Check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b9ErPQRSaar) working exapmle.

```js
let output = [{"_id":1,"order":1,"parent":0},{"_id":2,"order":2,"parent":0},{"_id":6,"order":1,"parent":2},{"_id":7,"order":2,"parent":2},{"_id":5,"order":3,"parent":0},{"_id":3,"order":1,"parent":5},{"_id":4,"order":2,"parent":5}];
let eOutput = [{"_id":1,"parent":0,"order":1},{"_id":2,"parent":0,"order":2},{"_id":6,"parent":2,"order":1},{"_id":7,"parent":2,"order":2},{"_id":5,"parent":0,"order":3},{"_id":3,"parent":5,"order":1},{"_id":4,"parent":5,"order":2}]

let matchedOutput = true;
for(let i=0; i< eOutput.length; i++){
  if(output[i]._id !== eOutput[i]._id ||
  output[i].parent !== eOutput[i].parent ||
  output[i].order !== eOutput[i].order){
    matchedOutput = false;
    break;
  }
}
console.log("Matched with expected output: ", matchedOutput);
```

Comment: In your given example it will not come according to order please check it again

Comment: It is working fine. No issue I have found. Check I have added one more JS snippet to match with your expected output.